# recommendation system for model in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recommendation-engine

I'm looking for recommendation system for my applicaiton which recommends albums based on the user purchased history. I found some system/algorithm like collaborative filtering (user/item/model/-based, hybrid). Which one is the best for my application? Or could you offer me some better solutions?

Comment: This is not a great question for this site as it is opinion based, overly broad and asks for a recommendation, any of which disqualifies it.

Comment: No matter what you chose you'll lose customers and money. That's because you don't understand what this system will do, what you expect it to produce or what "good" is. All cloud providers offer ML and recommendation services. How do you train and test them though?

Comment: To give an example of why this is off topic I could answer with "Use my Cheese Box rules engine, license is only $2m per server." as an answer.  I will happily build one for you for next week, cash up front.

Comment: SQL Server in 2016 added R services and in 2017 Python, which means you can use any ML/recommendation package out there, but you'll have to understand it, train it, experiment with parameters, evaluate performance and ensure you won't *lose* money. Even if you don't lose money directly, if your system is worse than the competition's you'll lose money indirectly. The tools are cheap. It's knowing what to do that's expensive

Answer (score 0):

There's no one-size fits all. Recommendation is an ongoing *process* that requires understanding, experimentation, evaluation of each approach not just on a technical level but a *business* level as well. Does the system generate enough revenue to justify its cost? Or are you losing money running the servers for no benefit?

Does the system end up recommending stuff with a *lower* margin than it should? That is, does it recommend stuff that's more expensive to procure or ship than other stuff?

Besides, past purchases are awful data. They tell you only what *you* sold the customer, not what the customer bought in general, what they like, why they like it etc. They don't tell you what they *didn't* buy. Or what they rejected from your own catalog before making a purchase. That's why companies buy data from market research companies.

I suggest reading [Building recommender systems with Azure Machine Learning service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/building-recommender-systems-with-azure-machine-learning-service/) not because it's Azure but because it explains the steps in that ongoing process, the various algorithms, what they are good for. There are at least 12 different algorithms in there.

The article explaines the 5 *ongoing* and repeating tasks in the process :

> 1. Data preparation - Preparing and loading data for each recommender algorithm
> 2. Modeling - Building models using various classical and deep learning recommender algorithms such as Alternating Least Squares (ALS) or eXtreme Deep Factorization Machines (xDeepFM)
> 3. Evaluating - Evaluating algorithms with offline metrics
> 4. Model selection and optimization - Tuning and optimizing hyperparameters for recommender models
> 5. Operationalizing - Operationalizing models in a production environment

Even if you have perfect data, 2-4 will be repeated over and over as you see what works or not for *your* business, whether it improved sales (and margins) or not.

The three big cloud providers offer various ways to create recommender services, for a monthly fee of course. The nice thing with cloud services at least is that you see the cost up front in your monthly bill.

Answer (score -1):

I've had good experience with the Python library [SurPRISE](http://surpriselib.com/). You can use it in a docker container to create a restful service and consume it from your ASP.NET web app.

Comment: Why that? And why a container, instead of just installing it on the same server? Why not one of the services provided by Amazon, Google or Amazon? Never mind that *every* recommendation system requires understanding. You can't just call it and expect to get good recommendations. That's a sure way to *lose* money

Comment: question says c# so this is not that.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the question doesn't really say anything. You can put the library inside SQL Server 2017 and call it using its Python language service, so you can call it from C#. That's why that service was added in the first place. But is it a good library? Based on what? Does the OP have the proper data, or a good way to experiment and evaluate models? If not, the recommendations will be random at best

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I suggest you read my first sentence again and try to parse it again

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine but this should be a comment, not an answer.